# Can't work : $_SESSION['qty'] = '$qty';

Tags: php, session

I'm making a shopping website and I faced a problem. When I filled in some numbers in quantity column, it will show the number as the end of the column. Is there domething wrong?

```
<tr align="center">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id;?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br><img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image; ?>" width='60' height="60"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>"/></td>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $update_qty="Update cart set qty='$qty'";
        $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);
        $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
    }                
    ?>                       
    <td><?php echo "$".$single_price; ?></td>
</tr>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16ydI.png]

Comment: Did you add `session_start()`?

Comment: where is your form tag?

Comment: Yes, I've already added session_start(). But it still don't work

Comment: Here it is!
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//allows you to start a session
session_start();
```

when you want to end the session

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Yes, I added session_start().

Answer (score 0):

You must start session before accessing any content
Add

```
session_start();
```

In the top of your file, under

```
<?php
```